# is there any reason for why we are restricting ourselves to the only the upper half-space of $\mathbb{R}^k$ in Munkres' book ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 200, it is given that

[image]

However, is there any reason for why we are restricting ourselves to the only the upper half-space of $\mathbb{R}^k$ ?

Comment: That is a prototype of a manifold with boundary. I think if you keep reading it will become more clear.

Comment: If you hate positive numbers but love negative numbers, you could restrict to the lower half plane instead.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks for the answer, please consider turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any affine hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane). $H$ is determined by two parameters $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $a \ne 0$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ as the set of all $x$ such that $a \cdot x = b$, where $a \cdot x$ denotes the usual dot product.

$H$ determines two closed halfspaces as the set of all $x$ such that $a \cdot x \ge b$ and $a \cdot x \le b$, respectively. The open halfspaces are defined similarly (via > and <).

For any two closed halfspaces there exists an affine isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^k$ mapping one to the other. This means that all closed halfspace have "equal rights".

$\mathbb{H}^k$ is given by $b = 0$ and $a = (0,..., 0,1)$ with $\ge$. This is just a nice and customary choice but does not have a compelling reason.